# How to cache a lazy-loaded property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

**Background:**

I have two tables `master` and `detail`. each row in `detail` contains propertyof `master` (lazy load).

I want to cache a collection of `detail` with their masters in a collection like the following:

```
List<Detail> cachedItems = entities.Details.ToList();

foreach (var d in cachedItems)
    d.master // throws exception
```

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

**The question:**

How can I cache the `master` object with the `detail` object without using another collection and I prefer to get them in one round-trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) function to shape your query results.

Comment: He can then cache the master with his underlying children.

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly get Master records before you close `ObjectContext`. If your navigation property in `Detail` entity is called `Master` modify your data retrieval query to:

```
List<Detail> cachedItems = entities.Details.Include("Master").ToList();
```

Or in case of using `Include` extension method form EF 4.1

```
List<Detail> cachedItems = entities.Details.Include(d => d.Master).ToList();
```

This will load are details with their masters immediately with one round-trip.